# Titlingpage environment from memoir - remove blankpage and let first page accept text

Tags: memoir

I am using the memoir class for my tex compilations. I am creating a scientific and simplified template for my old "paper". I came across the titling page environment and thought it was good enough. However, it introduces a blankpage after the first page and it inserts the content on the next page. Is it possible not to make that happen or would it be better to use another environment or approach? Reason is why I am trying to use it, is because I am trying to optimize my document from my former and it could take a long time to compile - and since titlingpage environment is from the memoir class, I thought it would make a more seamless process.

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue without any personal informations?

Comment: @Mensch Thanks a lot! Sorry if it wasn't transparent, but there is no error in my code, it was more of an question if there was a way of omitting the blank page and let content be on the titling page for the memoir class. I tried taking a look in the manual, but didn't find anything. But I am new, so I though I rather ask. Maybe titling page environment is not the best for the purpose I want. I'll take a picture from my former page setup and you'll see the general idea I wanted

Comment: I would not use memoir for scientific articles. Although it can emulate articles memoir is more for book and report like documents.

Comment: Or just don't use the titlingpage env

Comment: That would probably be a better option. I've never used anything else than memoir, so I am not sure what it would mean for my already understanding of how the class works, if I were to switch. I'll look up other options for articles and see If there is any significant differences. Thanks a lot :-).

Comment: @daleif I see no reason not to use `memoir` to produce documents that look as though they came from the `article` class. The manual suggests ignoring the `titlingpage` environment.